# Java 8 Function Reference With Arguments

Tags: java-8, method-reference

Trying to understand how to reference Instance functions. I've figured out how to define getters, but setters are giving me trouble. I'm not sure how to write a function for a given method signature and a given base class.

**What type is `Foo::setBar` below?**

```
public class Foo {
    private String bar;

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}


{
    //Works great!
    Function<Foo, String> func1 = Foo::getBar;

    //Compile error ?
    Function<Foo, String> func2 = Foo::setBar;
    //Compile error ?
    Function<Foo, Void, String> func3 = Foo::setBar;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `Function<Foo, String> func2 = Foo::setBar;` is a compile error, because `public void setBar(String bar)` ist not a function from `Foo` to `String`, it is actually a function from `String` to `Void`.

If you want to pass the setter as method reference, you need a BiConsumer, taking a `Foo` and a `String` like

```
final BiConsumer<Foo, String> setter = Foo::setBar;
```

Or if you already got an instance of `foo`, you can simply use this and use a `Consumer`, e.g.

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
final Consumer<String> setBar = foo::setBar;
```

Answer (score 3):

As `setBar` has a `void` return type, the matching functional interface single abstract method must have `void` return type as well. Such functional interfaces are commonly referred as "consumers". In your particular case you need to use [`BiConsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html) which accepts a `Foo` object and a new bar value:

```
BiConsumer<Foo, String> func2 = Foo::setBar;
```